# add liferay dockbar request

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to use liferay dockbar notifications. I succeeded in writing a notification into the database. But I actually would like to add a "request" rather than a "notification". What is the difference and how do I have to adjust my code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There's no shortage of room here: If you have 2 questions, please ask two questions, not one. This way you can accept two answers if they were helpful

Comment: Thanks, but you can only place one question per 45 minutes. As I had 3 questions, I shortened the procedure a bit by asking 2 together... But you are right, of course.

Comment: well, the 45 minutes are over now - please edit your question and decide which one to keep here